# findContours crashing compiler in OpenCV

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv, vector

I have now been trying for hours to figure out what is wrong in XCode when i try to use `findContours`. Basically this is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    Mat img = imread(helper::getImageSequence(3, image_value_temp));
    Mat img_gray = Mat(Size(img.cols, img.rows), CV_8UC1);
    Mat img_canny;

    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);    

    Canny(img_gray, img_canny, someLow, someHigh);

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(img_canny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
}
```

When i print contours i get 7905747460161236409, so i wonder if my heap is overflowing?

- XCode version: 4.5.2
- Compiler: Apple LLVM 4.1

So basically the crash traces back to `findContours` and this is all XCode gives me:

[image]

Comment: Can you please try to provide a Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example (http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @Dobi, Short? Yes. Self Contained? I cannot make it much more different, except `img` has to be replaced with an arbitrary image. Correct? Yep. Example? See the image below. In other words im not quite sure what your trying to state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to recreate your error if you would provide the full source code and the image that produce this error for you. When I complete your code, so that I can use it:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    using namespace cv;
    Mat img = imread("test.png");
    Mat img_gray = Mat(Size(img.cols, img.rows), CV_8UC1);
    Mat img_canny;

    cvtColor(img, img_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);    

    Canny(img_gray, img_canny, 80, 120);

    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(img_canny, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
}
```

It runs fine on my system. I do not see a reason why it should not.
The error you posted in the screenshot is not a compiler crash. Your debugger shows that your program crashed during executation.
You have a function circle_fitting_callback obviously written by yourself that produces an error while destructing a vector of cv::points. Your problem is not in the code you posted but in something you are not showing to us.
The best thing would be to learn to use your debugger. I do not know your IDE, but I guess it directly you to the part of your function causing the crash if you click the appropriate line in the call stack (the thing you showed to us).
If you get stuck with this please post a complete code to reproduce the error.

Comment: i tried to copy the exact piece of code into Visual Studio which compiled the code without any problems. I highly suspect that it might be some stack size im trying to exceed. `circle_fitting_callback` is indeed the function that runs the code described in my post. Unfortunately none of the steps in the debugger message points me back to a specific place, except for the closing bracket in `circle_fitting_callback` which is more og less useless.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can not help you with your problem if you do not provide all the code, that is necessary to reproduce it. Perhaps you are just doing a double deletion or some other basic mistake in your circle_fitting_callback function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I don't think you are suppose to run `findContours(...)` directly on the output of your Canny edge detector. The reason is that for some images, and for some values input parameters to the edge detector (in your case they are "someLow" and "someHigh"), the output image will have a lot of small fragmented edges. Hence, calling `findContours(...)` with the CV_RETR_TREE option (which returns a full hierarchy of nested contour) will cause it to find a lot of contours PLUS the extra overhead for contructing the hierarchy.

To test this, you can try running your code on a simple test image say of a solid circle with a solid colored background. The canny edge detector should give a single "edge" i.e. the circle. Then calling findContour(...) should give you this circle.

Another test would be to use CV_RETR_LIST instead of CV_RETR_TREE as CV_RETR_LIST returns just the contours without building the hierarchy.

Yet another test would be to run your code with inputs to the canny edge detector set in a way to return very few number of edges.

If these cases do not crash your program then we are roughly on the right track.

Lastly, from my experience doing image processing/computer vision work, you almost never want to call findContours(...) on an edge map because what for would you want contours around fragmented edges? If my guess is correct, you are trying to find contours around objects in your image. And if that is the case, then you should try to get a binary mask of the objects in your image using segmentation method such as [grabCut](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#void%20grabCut%28InputArray%20img,%20InputOutputArray%20mask,%20Rect%20rect,%20InputOutputArray%20bgdModel,%20InputOutputArray%20fgdModel,%20int%20iterCount,%20int%20mode%29) or [floodfill](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=grabcut#floodfill) (watershed, meanshift segmentation) etc., run some basic [image morphology](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphology-1) operators to clean up the mask and THEN run findContours(...) on this mask.

Hope this helps.